# CSV - delete/add columns or rows - Combine CSV files

Tags: csv, awk, sed, merge, paste

1. How can I merge 2 CSV files?
   If I try like this it doesn't add any columns but the 2 file as a new row?
   The columns are somehow never added at the end (after the last column). But always in the 2nd line or below at the end of the last row.
   product2.csv only has headings and no table content. Is that possibly because?
2. When I don't have a CSV file but still want to append a column. Can I do that with awk or sed?
3. How can I delete column 4?
4. How can i delete row 4?

I have try

```
paste -d, product1.csv product2.csv > result.csv
```

or

```
cat product1.csv product2.csv > result.csv
```

or

```
csvjoin -d ";" product1.csv product2.csv
```

product1.csv

```
Id;ReferenceNumber;EAN;Manu;Price_B2BR;Price_B2BD;Price_B2BDP;Price_B2BDA;Price_B2CEV;Price_B2CIV;VATRate;VATCountry;Currency;Stock;Delivery;StockNextDeliveryAccessVolume;WarrantyCode;EOL;Promotion;NonReturnable;RemainingStock;ImagePrimary;ImageAdditional;ProductLink;GrossWeight;NetWeight;RelatedProducts;AccessoryProducts;AA
3910112;BP9641;1,83E+10;APC;191;191;0;0;0;0;19;DE;EUR;8;;0;GH24;0;0;0;0;;;;0,34;;;;502,8
4640420;A-LTO7XSA;6,92E+11;Tandberg Data;1344,9;1344,9;0;0;3633;4214,28;19;DE;EUR;1;04.11.2023;1;GH36;0;0;0;0;;;;5,75;;;;438
5180134;403358811;2,80E+09;Intel;252,9;252,9;0;0;0;0;19;DE;EUR;0;;0;G24;1;0;0;0;;;;0,01;;;;16,44
1480155;100380;;Microsoft;11;11;0;0;14,32;16,61;19;DE;EUR;100;;0;;0;0;0;0;;;;0;;;;34,75
```

product2.csv

```
Can be Sold?;Can be Purchased?;Product Type;Category;Unit of Measure;Purchase Unit of Measure;Customer Taxes;Vendor Taxes;Invoicing Policy;Description for Customers;Quantity On Hand;image path/url
```

my result always looks like this:

result.csv

```
Id;ReferenceNumber;EAN;Manu;Price_B2BR;Price_B2BD;Price_B2BDP;Price_B2BDA;Price_B2CEV;Price_B2CIV;VATRate;VATCountry;Currency;Stock;Delivery;StockNextDeliveryAccessVolume;WarrantyCode;EOL;Promotion;NonReturnable;RemainingStock;ImagePrimary;ImageAdditional;ProductLink;GrossWeight;NetWeight;RelatedProducts;AccessoryProducts;AA
3910112;BP9641;1,83E+10;APC;191;191;0;0;0;0;19;DE;EUR;8;;0;GH24;0;0;0;0;;;;0,34;;;;502,8
4640420;A-LTO7XSA;6,92E+11;Tandberg Data;1344,9;1344,9;0;0;3633;4214,28;19;DE;EUR;1;04.11.2023;1;GH36;0;0;0;0;;;;5,75;;;;438
5180134;403358811;2,80E+09;Intel;252,9;252,9;0;0;0;0;19;DE;EUR;0;;0;G24;1;0;0;0;;;;0,01;;;;16,44
1480155;100380;;Microsoft;11;11;0;0;14,32;16,61;19;DE;EUR;100;;0;;0;0;0;0;;;;0;;;;34,75
Can be Sold?;Can be Purchased?;Product Type;Category;Unit of Measure;Purchase Unit of Measure;Customer Taxes;Vendor Taxes;Invoicing Policy;Description for Customers;Quantity On Hand;image path/url
```

But it should look like this:

```
Id;ReferenceNumber;EAN;Manu;Price_B2BR;Price_B2BD;Price_B2BDP;Price_B2BDA;Price_B2CEV;Price_B2CIV;VATRate;VATCountry;Currency;Stock;Delivery;StockNextDeliveryAccessVolume;WarrantyCode;EOL;Promotion;NonReturnable;RemainingStock;ImagePrimary;ImageAdditional;ProductLink;GrossWeight;NetWeight;RelatedProducts;AccessoryProducts;AA;Can be Sold?;Can be Purchased?;Product Type;Category;Unit of Measure;Purchase Unit of Measure;Customer Taxes;Vendor Taxes;Invoicing Policy;Description for Customers;Quantity On Hand;image path/url
3910112;BP9641;1,83E+10;APC;191;191;0;0;0;0;19;DE;EUR;8;;0;GH24;0;0;0;0;;;;0,34;;;;502,8;;;;;;;;;;;;
4640420;A-LTO7XSA;6,92E+11;Tandberg Data;1344,9;1344,9;0;0;3633;4214,28;19;DE;EUR;1;04.11.2023;1;GH36;0;0;0;0;;;;5,75;;;;438;;;;;;;;;;;;
5180134;403358811;2,80E+09;Intel;252,9;252,9;0;0;0;0;19;DE;EUR;0;;0;G24;1;0;0;0;;;;0,01;;;;16,44;;;;;;;;;;;;
1480155;100380;;Microsoft;11;11;0;0;14,32;16,61;19;DE;EUR;100;;0;;0;0;0;0;;;;0;;;;34,75;;;;;;;;;;;;
```

How does a CSV file recognize that a new line is coming? No matter what I merge it with, the 2nd file is always on the 2nd line. Why?

Comment: If you have to work with CSV-like files, you better use a specialized tool like csvkit or Miller. General CSV files are not a good fit for classic tools as awk and sed.

Comment: csvkit is csvjoin, so I have the same problem.

Comment: I was mostly answering your question number 2.

Comment: have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/75655773/757714

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to use paste and [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/6.7.0/installing-miller/).

> How can I merge 2 CSV files?

```bash
paste -d ";" product1.csv product2.csv > result.csv
```

You must use `-d ";"`, because in your files the field separator is `;`.

> When I don't have a CSV file but still want to append a column. Can I do that with awk or sed?

```bash
mlr --csv --fs ";" put '$newColumn="lorem ipsum"' input.csv >output.csv
```

How can I delete column 4?

```bash
mlr --csv --fs ";" --hi cut -x -f 4 input.csv>output.csv
```

`--hi` to set numbered implicit CSV header.

How can i delete row 4?

```bash
mlr --csv --fs ";" filter -x 'NR==4' input.csv>output.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, for brevity sake I would use other files, let `file1.csv` content be

```
id;name;price
1;Able;300
2;Baker;200
3;Charlie;100
```

and `file2.csv` content be

```
category;unit;taxes
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"}NR==1{append=$0;next}FNR==1{$0=$0 ";" append;fieldsnum=NF}{NF=fieldsnum;print}' file2.csv file1.csv
```

gives output

```
id;name;price;category;unit;taxes
1;Able;300;;;
2;Baker;200;;;
3;Charlie;100;;;
```

Explanation: I inform GNU `AWK` that semicolon is both field separator (`FS`) and output field separator (`OFS`) when processing 1st line globally (1st line of 1st file, observe that I ram `file2.csv` first) I simply store whole line (`$0`) in variable `append` and instruct GNU AWK to go to `next` line so nothing other is done, when processing 1st line of file (other than 1st) I concatenate whole line with `;` and `append`, save number of fields after that in variable `fieldsnum`, for each line but 1st line globally I set `NF` to computed number of fields and `print` it. If line has less fields new are added at end and are empty. If you want to know more about NR of FNR or NF then read [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Comment: Again, the columns are one below the other. Why?

`Can be Sold?;Can be Purchased?;Product Type;Category;Unit of Measure;Purchase Unit of Measure;Customer Taxes;Vendor Taxes;Invoicing Policy;Description for Customers;Quantity On Hand;image path/url;ProductId;ReferenceNo;EAN;Manufacturer;Price_B2BR;Price_B2BD;Price_B2BDP;Price_B2BDA;Price_B2CEV;Price_B2CIV;VATRate;VATCountry;Currency;Stock;Delivery;StockNextDeliveryAccessVolume;WarrantyCode;EOL;Promotion;NonReturnable;RemainingStock;ImagePrimary;ImageAdditional;ProductLink;GrossWeight;NetWeight;RelatedProducts;AccessoryProducts;AA`